# Webpack resolve giving undefined for exported variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, redux, webpack-4

I was using `Webpack 4` for bundling files in my current project. In order to avoid long paths in import statement, I was using `Resolve` key of the webpack configuration.

Currently, my config is something like this

```
{
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname,'src/'), 'node_modules']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(graphql|gql)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
      },
    ],
  },
```

It is working fine when I import any files. So instead of writing

```
import { STANDALONE_PATH } from '../../../url'
```

I can write

```
import { STANDALONE_PATH } from 'url'
```

- In case of any React component, it is working fine but if I import any variable or constant it's giving `undefined`

**src/constant.js**

```
export const message = "Hello world"
```

**src/components/card/message**

```
import { message } from 'constant'
console.log(message) //undefined
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use aliases for this purpose.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      constants$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/contants.js')
    }
  }
};
```

see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias for more information.